# When I check out a MVC Project that Uses EDMX I have to Hit Ctrl + S to update the model How Do i get around this when doing an automated Build

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entities, edmx

When I check out a MVC Project that Uses EDMX I have to Hit Ctrl + S to update the model before I Can build.  Otherwise I get a lot of build erros.   How Do i get around this when doing an automated Build

Comment: SalesSimplicityDB.Context.cs (1807): The type or namespace name 'CRM_GetNavigationDataForBuyerTab_Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Basically all the auto generated datatypes seem to cause a problem like this so If we get latest hit ctrl + S on the EDMX it goes away.  If we don't it gives us this error.  Seems with the automated build process this issue is unresolveable..

Comment: Is this a web site (File->New Web Site) or a web application project (File->New Project)?

Comment: That's the answer, then. Web sites "build" at runtime. What do you mean, "before I can build"?

Comment: CTRL+s causes code to be generated out of your EDMX file. Why don't you just check-in the auto gen-code?